# How to add CustomAction Id in Customization xml in ms dynamics CRM

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm, crm, dynamics-crm-4, dynamics-crm-online

Im a beginner to MS Dynamics CRM 2011 , and now need to add sample button in Ribbon.
Now i added CustomAction Id..  below CustomActions  in Customization.xml file , but while importing into CRM , it shows error.

```xml
<ImportExportXml xmlns:xsi="http://www.xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx">
.......
.....
<CustomActions >
<CustomAction Id=”Mscrm.ISV.MyCustomTabAction” Location=”Mscrm.Tabs._children” Sequence=”1000?>
       .....
....
      </CustomAction>
    </CustomActions >
<Templates>
  <RibbonTemplates Id="Mscrm.Templates"></RibbonTemplates>
</Templates>
      <CommandDefinitions>
      <CommandDefinition Id=”Mscrm.ISV.MyCustomTabCommand”>
       ......
      </CommandDefinition>
      </CommandDefinitions>
<RuleDefinitions>
  <TabDisplayRules />
  <DisplayRules >
    <DisplayRule Id=”Mscrm.ISV.MyCustomTabAction”>
       <OrRule>
          <Or>
            <CrmClientTypeRule Type=”Web” />   
          </Or>
        </OrRule>
       </DisplayRule>
</DisplayRules >
 .......
```

But when i open this xml in IE, its showing error,
"An invalid character was found in text content. Error processing resource 'file:///C:/Users/Vishnukumars/Desktop/CRM/custom...

```
<CustomAction Id="
```

Whats the error in

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have an error in you custom action ending with question mark.

```
Sequence=”1000?
```

Should be

```
Sequence=1000"
```

I would recommend to use a tool when modifying ribbons, like http://crmvisualribbonedit.codeplex.com/

Comment: yeah ok Bassetassen.. let me check with that. tnx